# Can't add Mysql.Data as reference after installing Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mysql.data

I have VS 2010 Professional installed in my machine. I tried to download VS 2012 Express to check this out. I explore this and tried to create a sample website. But when I tried to add Mysql.Data, I cannot add it. When I tried to add reference in Assembly>Extension, Mysql.Data is there I add it, but I figured out that it didn't add in the reference and I cannot use this.

Here's some solution that I've tried:

1. Delete packages at C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio
2. Tried to uninstall and reinstall mysql.data library

Can you help me to fix this one? THanks alot!

Comment: create new project. install mysql extension via nuget. try it.

Comment: thank you so much kabayan! sorry newbie sa VS2012 XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for the people who will have the same experience as me.

You can see the comment of 'JW'. That's the correct answer.

Install mysql.data extension via nuget:

1. In WEBSITE/PROJECT tab look for 'Manage NuGet Packages'.
2. Search mysql.data and Install

Done!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with VS 2010 ,  
I would manage to solve the problem with reinstalling mysql Database.  
here is the link to download : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=413555 
make sure :  
1-uninstall wamp or xamp server.  
2- you have checked the C# and Visual Studio once you are installing MySQL database . 
 
3- close VS , and open it again.  
you will be finding the MYSQL.data in the add referencing list.

Answer (score 0):

I have just gone through mySQL Forums and found Visual Studio 2012 integration with mySQL Connector v.6.5.5

We'll be adding support for VS 2012 in Connector/NET 6.5.5 and later 6.6.x version 
Meantime, please try the workaround mentioned already:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,546265,555870#msg-555870

Answer (score 0):

I am bit late but recently i was having the same problem. and luckily I worked it out. you can add it manually by going to the **Tools** menu, select **Library Package Manager** and then click **Package Manager Console**.
and then put the below code in to console and you done.

> Install-Package MySql.Data

for referance you can go to the [Link](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install MySQL Connector/NET from the MySQL official website
2. Right click your project in Solution Explorer
3. Click Add reference
4. Click Browse
5. look in: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MySql.Data\v4.0_8.0.11.0__c5687fc88969c44d
6. Done!